# Move to last non-empty line in vim

Tags: vim, vi

Say that I have the following beginning of file. I often navigate to the top of the file with `gg`, but then I want to go to line 4, i.e. last non-empty line so that I can import other stuff on a new line with `o`. Is there a command to do that? Of course I could do `4j` and then `o`, but the number of import lines varies across files, so in order to avoid having to look for this information everytime it could be nice just to go to the last non-empty line with a single command, so that I could simply type ´o´ and start writing.

```
  1 import * as firebase from 'firebase';
  2 import { firebaseConfig } from '.././config/auth';
  3 import { RkText, RkCard, RkStyleSheet, RkTheme } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
  4 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  5
  6 [some other code]
  ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to go to *the first empty line* with `}` (go forward paragraph) and insert with `O`.

see `:help object-motions` for details.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, will accept when I can (says I have to wait 9 minutes)...

Comment: I would use `}` followed by `i`.

Comment: That depends on if you want to keep the blank line (which I think the OP wanted since using o in the question)  Boils down to if shift or return is more expensive ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Upper case G gets you to the last line of the file.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't specify that line 5 wasn't the end of the file - just tried to do that...